# Why does my Apex visualforce email template change html hyperlinks in APEX Repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

Why does my Apex visualforce email template change html hyperlinks in APEX Repeat

Code for apex repeat:

```
                     <apex:repeat var="QP" value="{!recipient.Quoted_Products__r}">
                        <tr>
                        <td  style="font-size:14px; color:black;font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif; border-bottom: solid 1px black;"><a href="{!QP.Quote_Email_Product_URL__c}">{!QP.Product__c}</a></td>
                        <td align="right"  style="font-size:14px; color:black; border-bottom: solid 1px black; nowrap">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${!QP.Amount__c}0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td  style="font-size:10px; color:black;font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;nowrap"><div style="padding-left: 20px;">{!QP.Description__c}</div><br></br></td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
```

URL that is set by {!QP.Quote_Email_Product_URL__c} but the email template shows the URL as "/https://www.createspace.com/Services/TemplateInterior.jsp".  Why is it adding an extra "/" before the URL address?

Comment: Does the leading "/" not occur if you output the field separately (not in the repeat)?

Comment: I had something similar but the "/" was not appearing. Could you check if the "/" is not in the field value too?

Comment: There was a / in the html email template. I removed it, but now the APEX repeat is removing a / from the address so it appears https:/www.createspace.com

href now looks like this in apex repeat "<a href="{!QP.Quote_Email_Product_URL__c}">{!QP.Product__c}</a>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  You cannot use href in APEX repeat without issues.  I used apex:outputLink:

***<****apex:outputLink value="{!QP.Quote_Email_Product_URL_*c}">{!QP.Product*_c}</apex:outputLink>*****